# Gatsby SSR for dynamic website metadata not working

Tags: reactjs, seo, gatsby, server-side-rendering

I've been following the Gatsby Tutorial on how to implement SSR in a gatsby site [according to this article](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/rendering-options/using-server-side-rendering/). This link suggests that I add `export async function getServerData() {...}` function in my page and `serverData` as a prop. This tutorial suggests that doing so will result in Gatsby using SSR for my site and I'll be able to retreive any data before page is loaded.

However, this is not the case, after following the exact tutorial, I don't get any dog images and I get an error saying `serverData` is undefined

My SSR code looks like this

```js
import * as React from "react"

const SSRPage = ({ serverData }) => (
  <main>
    <h1>SSR Page with Dogs</h1>
    <img alt="Happy dog" src={serverData.message} />
  </main>
)

export default SSRPage

export async function getServerData() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random`)
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Response failed`)
    }
    return {
      props: await res.json(),
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      status: 500,
      headers: {},
      props: {}
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have tried running my site with `gatsby build && gatsby serve` as well as with just `gatsby serve` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Where's your `SSRPage` located?

Comment: it is under `src/pages` directory

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I found the solution if anyone runs into a similar problem. The basic issue was I using Gatsby v3 whereas SSR was introduced in Gatsby v4.

If anyone encounters this issue, please update to v4 and try again.

Moreover, in your `gatsby-config.js` file, make sure to add this flag:

```
module.exports = {
  ...    // your existing config
  flags: {
    DEV_SSR: true,
  },
  ...
}
```

This'll enable logging for SSR in dev version